# multiple ifelse statements - some not working

Tags: r, if-statement, variables

Very new to R, I'm trying to create a variable 'Accuracy' based on different conditions:

If first row is Image2, and image2 is selected from rows 2 to 40 then assign 1. If first row is Image2, and image1 is selected from rows 42 to 80 then assign 1. If first row is Image1, and image1 is selected from rows 2 to 40 then assign 1. If first row is Image1, and image2 is selected from rows 42 to 80 then assign 1

If none of these are satisfied then assign 0.

The first 2 statements work fine, but the last 2 don't, any suggestions would be appreciated

```
data1$Accuracy <- ifelse(data1$Correct_image[1] == "Image2" & between(data1$Trial_number, 2, 40) & data1$Image_selected == "image2", 1,
                  ifelse(data1$Correct_image[1] == "Image2" & between(data1$Trial_number, 42, 80) & data1$Image_selected == "image1", 1,
                  ifelse(data1$Correct_image[1] == "Image1" & between(data1$Trial_number, 2, 40) & data1$Image_selected == "image1", 1,
                  ifelse(data1$Correct_image[1] == "Image1" & between(data1$Trial_number, 42, 80) & data1$Image_selected == "image2", 1, 0))))
```

Comment: One possibility is to use `case_when`, which allows you to vectorise multiple if else statements.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

As @yang-wu suggested, dplyr's case_when is a good fit for this case.

```
library(dplyr)
data1 %>%
  mutate(Accuracy = case_when(
    Correct_image == "Image2" & between(Trial_number,  2, 40) & Image_selected == "image2" ~ 1,
    Correct_image == "Image2" & between(Trial_number, 42, 80) & Image_selected == "image1" ~ 1,
    Correct_image == "Image1" & between(Trial_number,  2, 40) & Image_selected == "image1" ~ 1,
    Correct_image == "Image1" & between(Trial_number, 42, 80) & Image_selected == "image2" ~ 1, 
    TRUE ~ 0))))
  ))
```

Comment: If this doesn't work, it will be hard to resolve your question without some code to produce example data and expected output.

Comment: Also, what specifically does "some not working mean" here? What did you expect and how was the result different from that?

Answer (score 0):

All conditions evaluate to either 1 or 0, so you can also put them all in a single (although long) ifelse call:

```
data1$Accuracy <- ifelse((data1$Correct_image[1] == "Image2" & between(data1$Trial_number, 2, 40) & data1$Image_selected == "image2")|
                                 (data1$Correct_image[1] == "Image2" & between(data1$Trial_number, 42, 80) & data1$Image_selected == "image1")|
                                 (data1$Correct_image[1] == "Image1" & between(data1$Trial_number, 2, 40) & data1$Image_selected == "image1")|
                                 (data1$Correct_image[1] == "Image1" & between(data1$Trial_number, 42, 80) & data1$Image_selected == "image2"),1,0)
```

It is not possible to go any further without seeing the data.

For instance, if Correct_image[1] is a char variable and there are only two levels to Correct_image[1] and Image_selected, there may be some simpler solutions such as:

```
#1 - a little modification so 'image1' and 'Image1' are no longer different:

data1$Correct_image[1]<-tolower(data1$Correct_image[1])
#2 simpler conditions in case_when():

data1$Accuracy<-case_when(data1$Correct_image[1]==data1$Image_selected & between(data1$Trial_number, 2, 40) ~ 1,
                          data1$Correct_image[1]!=data1$Image_selected & between(data1$Trial_number, 42, 80) ~1,
                          TRUE ~ 0)
```